# Google App Engine Domain Mapping Issue Through CNAME

Tags: google-app-engine, domain-mapping

I have my base app hosted in GCP App Engine.
The base domain for this app is `app.xyz.com`

I have user based subdomain dashboard access.

Eg. User 1 can have their subdomain `xyz.pqr.com` and then map it to my base domain
`app.xyz.com`

User 2 can have their subdomain `example2.com` and then map it to my base domain
`app.xyz.com`

I want the mapping to be done through CNAME only. i.e User have to change the cname to map with my base domain.

However while visiting these subdomain its landing me to google 404 page.

I want App engine to serve content to my base domain and all domain mapped to it.

In app engine, I have added *.xyz.com as domain mapping with traffic proxied through cloudflare using origin server ssl certificate.

Currently i can access the app through any subdomain like `v1.xyz.com` or `v2.xyz.com`  buy not through `v1.abc.com`  Which is currently mapped to app.xyz.com through cname

[image]

current ssl settings for Cloudflare in Full mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally fixed it using a https load balancer:

Backend -> `App Engine Instance`
Frontend -> `app.xyz.com`

`v1.abc.com` -> `app.xyz.com` via `CNAME`

Answer (score 0):

`v1.abc.com` isn't actually mapped **yet** to `app.xyz.com`.

What you've done is essentially to say - if you're looking for `v1.abc.com`, talk to Google's servers.

Now, you have to tell Google's servers - when you receive traffic from `v1.abc.com`, you should serve up the App at `appId` (your App Id). This means you have to add a mapping from `v1.abc.com` on your GAE custom domains tab.

Simply put - to build a service where users can map their custom domains to your AppId, you have to add a mapping for each user's custom domain

Comment: So for my clients sub domain I have to map it to app engine every time. It should be a problem but google has system for the domain to be verified and they allow mapping